# DllImport causing access violation exception

Tags: c#, dllimport, unmanaged, access-violation, managed

The C dll header is this:

```
HRESULT App_Process(char *FileName, char *Output, const bool& LogInformation);
```

My C# DllImport looks like this:

```
[DllImport("App.dll")]
public static extern Int32 App_Process(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string FileName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string Output,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool LogInformation);
```

The exception is:

```
var result = App_Process("MyFile.txt", "Output.txt", true);
```

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Now the strange this is that the method is successfully doing everything its supposed to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps last parameter should be a `ref bool`?

Comment: All the `MarshalAs` attributes are pointless, merely restating the defaults as they do. Last param is `ref bool`. Calling convention is unknown. And it looks like the two string parameters could be output parameters because they are `char*` rather than `const char*`. I suggest that you read the documentation for this library before attempting to call it.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yes the ref bool solved the problem. Post it as an answer please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original answer**

The last parameter of the extern method should be a `ref bool` rather than `bool`, given that the DLL header has a parameter of type `const bool&`:

```
// Parameter names changed to be idiomatic for C#
[DllImport("App.dll")]
public static extern Int32 App_Process(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string fileName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string output,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] ref bool logInformation);
```

With C# 7.2 I suspect you could use `in` instead of `ref`, which would make the method simpler to call:

```
// Parameter names changed to be idiomatic for C#
[DllImport("App.dll")]
public static extern Int32 App_Process(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string fileName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string output,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] in bool logInformation);
```

**Update**

(From the comment from Hans Passant)

This is not C code, as `bool&` is only valid in C++. That makes it very likely that the argument needs to be marshalled as `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]`. Double-check with `sizeof(bool)` in the native code. But you should talk to the author of the DLL, as `const bool&` makes no sense at all. There's no point in passing a bool by reference but then not allowing the code to update it.

Comment: This is not C code, bool& is only valid in C++.  Which makes it very likely that the argument needs [MarshalAs(UnamagedType.U1)].  Double-check with sizeof(bool) in the native code.  The OP *really* needs to talk to the author, const bool& makes no sense at all.  No point in passing a bool by reference but then not allowing to update it.

Comment: @HansPassant: I've updated the answer to just include your comment almost verbatim. We'll see if the OP sees it...